# Проверка на существование значений в объекте

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите есть ли какая то стандартная проверка:
К примеру есть объект с данными в виде

```
{
   param: 1,
   param2: 1,
   p: 1,
   s: 1
   .......
}
```

Нужно проверить существует ли в объекте хотя бы одно значение. Т.е. в случае если

```
{
   param: '',
   param2: 0,
   p: 0,
   s: ''
   .......
}
```

Получить false

Или придется цикл строить?

Comment: Насколько знаю, способов из коробки нет, но функция проверки пишется в одну строчку:

    function isEmptyObject(o) {for (var k in o) if (o[k]) return false; return true;}

Comment: @webphp, вы знаете способы перебрать некое множество элементов чего-либо и обойтись без циклов? Или у вас идейное предубеждение против циклов?

Comment: klopp, на это и существуют функции из "коробки". Зачем писать костыли, если есть уже что то готовое. Но так как нет, то и говорить особо не о чем.

Comment: @webphp, что вы считаете значением, а что нет?

Comment: dzhioev, 

    {
       key: 'value'
    }

у вас другое мнение?

Comment: @webphp, имеется в виду, например, будет ли [] считаться за непустое значение.

Comment: Etk, в объекте у кличей значение может быть только строка или цифра, массивов там нет, а так то да, [] должно считаться пустым значением.

В любом случае всем спасибо =) буду юзать цикл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно знаю!

```
if(!obj['param'] || !obj['param2'] || !obj['p'] || !obj['s']) {
    error_key = true;
}
```

А так да, встроенной функции по обработке ассоциативных массивов вроде как не припоминаю, в общем как-то так:

```
var obj = {
    param: 1,
    param2: 1,
    p: 1,
    s: 1
}
,   error_key = false;

for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !obj[key]) {
        error_key = true;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(error_key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj ={
'key': 'val',
'key1': 'val1'
'key2': 'val2'
}

const check_val = 'val1'

function checkObj(obj, check_val){
return Object.values(obj).includes(check_val)
}
```